# Why does the ClientID not show up? How to fix

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a jQuery function in ASP that I am trying to get the client ID of. When It renders the HTML I get this as a result.

[HTML RENDERED]

```
$("")//ctl00_Content_gvProgramList
                    .tablesorter({ widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra'],
                        widgetOptions: {
                            zebra: ["even", "odd"]
                        }
                    })
                    .tablesorterFilter({ filterContainer: $("#filter-box"),
                        filterClearContainer: $("#filter-clear-button"),
                        filterColumns: [0, 1, 2, 3],
                        filterCaseSensitive: false
                    })
                    .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager") });
```

[CODE BEHIND]

```
        $("<%# gvProgramList.ClientID %>")//ctl00_Content_gvProgramList
                .tablesorter({ widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra'],
                    widgetOptions: {
                        zebra: ["even", "odd"]
                    }
                })
                .tablesorterFilter({ filterContainer: $("#filter-box"),
                    filterClearContainer: $("#filter-clear-button"),
                    filterColumns: [0, 1, 2, 3],
                    filterCaseSensitive: false
                })
                .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager") });
```

If i use `ct100_Content_gvProgramList` all the javascript works like it should, so please don't post any answers relating to that. I want an answer on how to get the `ClientID` to show up correctly.

---

### update

I would like to use  `$('#<%= gvProgramList.ClientID %>')`, but I get an error.

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). 

Line 16:         Head.Controls.Add(Header())
Line 17:         Head.Controls.Add(Menu())
Line 18:         Foot.Controls.Add(Footer())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
<%= ... %>
```

Instead of:

```
<%# ... %>
```

So:

```
$('#<%= gvProgramList.ClientID %>') ...
```

---

**After Update**

Since you're building/modifying the controls collection in the *code-behind* aspnet is barfing when you try to `Response.Write()` (`<%= ... %>`). Try using a class name instead of the control's `id`.

Or:

Wrap the `<script> ... </script>` inside an `<asp:placeholder>`. This will make the script a child of the place holder instead of the server-side control that is causing the error.

Comment: Plus adding `#` in front of the selector.

Comment: Unless of course you have `Page.DataBind()` in the codebehind which makes using the **#** valid.  Databinding the page with the intent to use the **#** was actually quite common way back when in order to circumvent some Ajax Control Toolkit issues, most commonly with the ValidatorCalloutExtenders.  /end triva.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo there may be an even simpler solution if you provide a snippet of the rendered markup that contains the "control".

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to replace the binding with a placeholder control that you populate in the code-behind. So in the .aspx/.ascx file, you would replace this:

```
$('#<%= gvProgramList.ClientID %>')
```

With this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="phProgramListClientId" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Then in your code-behind, you can do this:

```
phProgramListClientId.Controls.Add( new LiteralControl( 
    String.Format( "$('#{0}')", gvProgramList.ClientID ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%# ... %>
```

is for data binding so you can do this

```
Page.DataBind();
```